# Make CEF use separate executable to launch subprocesses (C++/Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, process, chromium-embedded

I am trying to modify the "cefsimple" example from the Chromium Embedded Framework (https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/Tutorial), so that it uses a **separate executable** in order to launch its sub-processes on Windows.

However, this is not working as expected and it crashes every time on the call to **CefInitialize** in the main process, before any window pops up or any subprocess is launched. Call stack:

```
    chrome_elf.dll!00007ffaa7fc1cfd()   
    chrome_elf.dll!00007ffaa7fba5fc()   
    chrome_elf.dll!00007ffaa7fb9c9b()   
    libcef.dll!00007ffa88dae13c()   
    libcef.dll!00007ffa882fc146()   
>   cefsimple.exe!CefInitialize(const CefMainArgs & args, const CefStructBase<CefSettingsTraits> & settings, CefRefPtr<CefApp> * application, void * windows_sandbox_info)  Line 201 + 0xb4 bytes   C++
```

**Using**: CEF version 3.2883.1539, 64-bit, C++, VS 2015, Windows 10.

**My solution**:
I added another target (cefsimpleHelper.exe) in the CMakeLists, and used these instructions as a reference to modify the source code:
https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage#markdown-header-separate-sub-process-executable

**cefsimple_win.cc:** *(entry point of the main executable)*

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                      HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                      LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                      int       nCmdShow)
{
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

  CefEnableHighDPISupport();
  CefMainArgs main_args(hInstance);

  CefSettings settings;
  settings.no_sandbox = true;
  CefString(&settings.browser_subprocess_path).FromASCII("cefsimpleHelper.exe");

  CefRefPtr<SimpleApp> app(new SimpleApp);

  CefInitialize(main_args, settings, app.get(), NULL);
  CefRunMessageLoop();
  CefShutdown();

  return 0;
}
```

**process_helper_win.cc:** *(entry point for the sub-process launcher)*

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
    int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    CefMainArgs main_args(hInstance);
    CefRefPtr<SimpleApp> app(new SimpleApp);
    return CefExecuteProcess(main_args, app.get(), nullptr);
}
```

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: You can try to debug it and find out which line of CEF/Chromium source code caused the crash. You just need debug symbols from cefbuilds.com and CEF source code from https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef. You would probably need Chromium code too. It's a bit trickier but there is an instruction here: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code

Comment: Your main exe is being launched twice, second time is the new crashpad process, check the issue tracker for details, there is an open issue. chrome_elf.dll is was added specifically for crashpad support.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the solution, mostly by random trial and error :P

I've just added a call to **CefExecuteProcess** in the main executable, before **CefInitialize**:

```
const auto exit_code = CefExecuteProcess(main_args, app.get(), nullptr);
if (exit_code >= 0)
    return exit_code;
```

Thanks for all the comments, I hope this will help others as well.